# C# for loop that gives sum of i/(i+1) through user specificed number

Tags: c#

I need to display sum(i) = 1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 + ... i/(i+1) where the final i is specified by the user. For some reason I am getting error "**use of unassigned variable**" for the second "total" in this line of code:

```
double total = (double) total + (i / (i + 1));
```

I tried to declare total outside the for loop but then it always comes out equal to 0.

Here is the full code:

```
public static void DisplaySums(int lastNum)
{
    Console.WriteLine("i\tSum(i)");
    for (int i=1; i<=(lastNum); i++)
    {
        double total = (double) total + (i / (i + 1));
        Console.WriteLine(i + "\t" + total);                
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter an integer: ");
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    DisplaySums(n);
```

This is my first time ever asking a question on StackOverflow so I hope this makes sense. I can clarify if needed!

Thank you :)

Comment: Not the cause of problem, but important: `(i / (1 + 1))` - integer division here. I guess, you may want to cast `i` to `double` before dividing to get `double` result.

Comment: You cannot declare a variable, initialize it and at the same time use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to declare `total` outside of the loop. Else you are not summing up any intermediate results.

Second, you're getting zero because

```
(i / (i + 1))
```

performs integer division which is automatically truncated. To keep the decimal number, use a double literal:

```
(i / (i + 1.0))
```

Comment: @n0tthesun well, the integer result is casted to double, but that happens after it was already truncated. That's why it doesn't work. What does work is casting 1 to double `(i / (i + (double)1))` what imo looks ugly. You could also write `1d` instead of `1.0`.

Comment: Yes I agree, it looks better to just use 1.0. or 1d. Thank you for explaining that.

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
double total = (double) total + (i / (i + 1));
```

You are essentially saying `total` is equal to itself plus something else. However the compiler doesn't know what `total` is as you just declared it. You need to assign the variable before you can use it.

Also `(i / (i + 1))` is integer division. Which from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/division-operator):

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer

Anything divided by itself plus one will not be a whole number and the remainder will get thrown away and `0` will be returned. To fix this change `(i / (i + 1))` to `(i / (i + 1.0))`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here; the biggest obviously being your compile time error *use of unassigned variable*. This is because you are trying to assign the value of your newly instantiated variable as it is instantiated. A good idea is to instantiate to zero. You should also do this outside of your loop to retain the value with every iteration.

```
double total = 0;
Console.WriteLine("i\tSum(i)");
for (int i = 1; i <= lastNum; i++) {
    total += (i / (i + 1));
    Console.WriteLine(i + "\t" + total);
}
```

The next issue you are having is the result of zero every time. This is because the division is being performed on integers and integers are any whole number, thus a value such as `0.25` is rounded down to `0`. If you revise your loop and your parameter in your method to use the `double` type instead, this issue will be resolved:

```
private static void DisplaySums(double lastNum) {
    double total = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("i\tSum(i)");
    for (double d = 1; d <= lastNum; d++) {
        total += (d / (d + 1));
        Console.WriteLine(d + "\t" + total);
    }
}
```

Comment: May be, just post your answer when you fill it with all the detail?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev It takes me a moment to type. Therefore I let the user know I am responding to their issue, and then fill it in. There is no issue with doing this as it provides initial feedback.